# Logging off Viber account on my stolen phone

Tags: viber-messenger

I lost my phone last Friday, May 31. I was able to get already a replacement SIM card for me to use the same no. again for my new phone now. My Facebook was already hacked yesterday since my FB app in my lost phone was open just like my emails and VIBER accounts.

With this, I would like to know how to log off Viber on all devices that I previously opened so my info will not be compromised.

My Viber is now open on my new phone and my laptop but I want it to log off in my lost phone and all other devices.

Is this possible just like Chrome, or Google, Yahoo, and even Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are able to use Viber on your new phone means that it is logout of the former as explained [here](https://support.viber.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2914872-protecting-your-privacy-on-viber):

> **Lost or stolen phones**
>
> If you have lost your phone, or it has been stolen, you can deactivate Viber by simply reactivating your account with the same phone number on a new phone.
>
> Setting up Viber on a new phone will close your account on the old device, and no one will be able to access the chats stored in there.

For other apps such as Facebook, Gmail, etc., change your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Activate it on a friends phone, then deactivate it on the same phone. It will deactivate your account on all phones and PCs.